# Running WikiMedia lua script or expanding API module output

Tags: php, lua, dependencies, mediawiki

I have two specific questions and I hope someone can answer either of them:

1. Is there a way to provide MediaWiki's `mw` library to a stand-alone lua script?
2. Is there an API command or property that exposes the output of a dynamic module?

Background: I am trying to figure out how to access the output of a wiktionary module (in this case, `pron-th`). This is a module that can be dynamically inserted by editors to show transliteration (pronunciation) of Thai words. For example, whenever an editor has added this line:

```
 {{th-pron|ไคฺร่}}
```

...the server will run the Lua script documented found [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Module:th-pron) and outputs a table showing the various transliterations ([example](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%B9%83%E0%B8%84%E0%B8%A3%E0%B9%88#Thai)). However, this output is specifically excluded when doing API requests ([example](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=query&prop=revisions&rvprop=content&format=json&formatversion=2&titles=%E0%B9%83%E0%B8%84%E0%B8%A3%E0%B9%88)) and I cannot find an endpoint that includes this data. And running the lua script directly fails because it is missing several imports, such as `mw.ustring`, `mw.text`, etc., which I believe are defined in a PHP include higher up their software stack. I have significant PHP experience but none with Lua, so I am sort of at a loss here.

Short of calling up each page directly and scraping the data, I can't think of a way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MediaWiki mw library is part of the Scribunto extension (see https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-extensions-Scribunto/tree/master/includes/engines/LuaCommon/lualib), and has a lot of dependencies back to MEdiawikis php core, so it won't be easy to just import that.

You could render that wikitext via API like [https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=parse&text=%20{{th-pron|%E0%B9%84%E0%B8%84%E0%B8%BA%E0%B8%A3%E0%B9%88}}&contentmodel=wikitext](https://en.wiktionary.org/w/api.php?action=parse&text=%20%7B%7Bth-pron%7C%E0%B9%84%E0%B8%84%E0%B8%BA%E0%B8%A3%E0%B9%88%7D%7D&contentmodel=wikitext) and parse the output, or you could try and replace the MediaWiki specific function calls with other function calls to some native Lua library.

Comment: Thanks. Right now, this does indeed look like the right answer. Sorry for the delay in accepting. I'm not 100% sure that the lua scripts can't be run without PHP integration, but I can't see how to do it myself (it is so weird having two-way dependency graphs span interpreted languages like this). I will probably keep working at this as long as I think there's a possibility I can get it working.

Comment: Yeah the Scribunto implementation is certainly interesting, they literally have their own php extension to make it work.